# How to customize a boxplot in SAS?

Tags: sas

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnLHh.png)The data I am looking at is different genes (categories) and the number of them (continuous) and the outcome of having cancer (dichotomous/ yes or no).
I am trying to create a boxplot of my data in SAS and want them all on the same boxplot instead of individual. My y axis should be my number and my x axis I want all of my genes and have those in two group of having cancer or not. How would I do this? I have tried using Proc Boxplot but couldn't figure out what to do. Below is the code I tried but I could not seem to add multiple variables to it.

```
ods graphics on;
 ods html;
 proc boxplot data=genes2;
 plot A6_A8*cancer_status;
   by cancer_status;
 run; 
ods html close;
ods graphics off;
```

Comment: It depends a lot on your data structure so you may want to post example data so we can help you out. Personally, I recommend using SGPLOT and HBOX/VBOX instead as you can then make more complicated plots and have more customization options.

Comment: If you google search the following you'll find many full worked code examples though: "boxplot site:blogs.sas.com". One of them will be this example, the code is at the bottom of the page to download and use.

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2019/03/06/proc-boxplot-hundreds.html

Comment: Welcome, Daniel. Please note that stack overflow is a knowledge base of developers. It is not a chat box, so save us your personal stories, and most of us don't know anything about genetics or statistics, so translate your questions to our jargon, please. It also helps to show us your data and what you tried so far, both to have more response and to increase the chance our answer is to the point and understandable for you. For more information, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and I have updated the post accordingly.